Grub does not see LinuxMint when dual boot Fedora 40 and LinuxMint 24 on external SSD
So I installed on my external SSD both LinuxMint 24 and Fedora 40. Here is how:

Partition table of SSD: GPT and split my SSD in 500GB Ext4 and 500GB empty
First installed LinuxMint on empty with manual partitioning
Made EFI System Partition
Made /boot (was a requirement because of my "/" that is encrypted LVM) (Ext4 and primary)
Made / encrypted LVM (Ext4 and primary)
LinuxMint succesfully installed
Deleted then 500GB Ext4 and made it empty
Second installed Fedora 40
Deleted LinuxMint EFI System Partition (which is basically FAT32 /boot/efi). Reason is that Fedora when install throws an error. So I figured that Fedora would make the Grub that would recognize LinuxMint. I was forced to do this.
Choose automatic install with encryption on the empty space
Fedora succesfully installed

Here the result:
Disks
Problem is that LinuxMint is not recognized in my Grub 2.06.
I tried to update GRUB:
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg but nothing. Also tried adding GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false to /etc/default/grub and rerun grub2 but nothing. The same when adding GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false also nothing.
Funny enough os-prober has no output, nothing happens.
I also tried doing a manual entry:
menuentry 'linux mint' { set root=(hd1,2) configfile /grub2/grub.cfg }
But since I use an external SSD I am not sure how to set the root.
I was thinking that /boot (for LinuxMint) and /boot/efi (for Fedora) is where the issue lies. Or perhaps that I set the LinuxMint partition to primary and better would be logical?
How to make GRUB (Fedora 40) also recognize my LinuxMint? I can perfectly boot into Fedora 40 and GRUB menu shows, but no LinuxMint entry nowhere.

FYI:  You specify encryption but not which you're using, ie. LUKS1 or LUKS2 as Ubuntu media for example can install/use both, and it does make a difference in relation to your actual problem.

The latest version of Linux Mint is 21.3

Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

I was having a similar issue and sudo update-grub worked for me on linux mint.
